# How do I pivot into generated columns?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I currently have a SQL query that creates the following output:

```
+---------+----------+
| Project |    ID    |
+---------+----------+
| X       | Tom      |
| X       | Matt     |
| X       | Steve    |
| Y       | Richard  |
| Y       | Tom      |
| Y       | Garfield |
| Y       | Katie    |
+---------+----------+
```

I need to pivot it to look like the following:

```
+---------+---------+------+----------+-------+--+
| Project |   ID    | ID1  |   ID2    |  ID3  |  |
+---------+---------+------+----------+-------+--+
| X       | Tom     | Matt | Steve    |       |  |
| Y       | Richard | Tom  | Garfield | Katie |  |
+---------+---------+------+----------+-------+--+
```

The background is that I have a table of events generated by the server, and a table of users who have a certain permission level by project. If I merge these, the events table explodes in size and later on the workflow uses record count for a few things. So I would just like to use project as a key and bring over a list of users with a particular permission level as additional columns.

The largest difficulty is that this needs to be dynamic, as permissions are reassigned and projects are created/deleted.

Comment: Share your effort.

Comment: Not possible. The number of columns of a query must be known to the database **before** the query is actually executed. If you need to cope with a varying number of users you could return the users as a single array, e.g. `select project, array_agg(id) from the_table group by project`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Truly, you can't. In SQL, the number of columns returned is defined by the query you send, never by the resultset itself.

However, you can use an array (= variable number of values in a single column). Use the following as a sub-query:

```
SELECT project, array_agg(id)
FROM T
GROUP BY project
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `conditional aggregation`

**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=430c2913288e2e2c055deabc96e649f1)**

```
select project, 
       max(case when rn=1 then id end) as ID, 
       max(case when rn=2 then id end) ID1,
       max(case when rn=3 then id end) as ID2, 
       max(case when rn=4 then id end) as ID3
from
(
select Project,id, row_number() over(partition by project order by null) as rn
from tablename
)A group by project
```

OUTPUT:

```
project id    id1     id2       id3
X       Tom   Steve   Matt  
Y       Katie Richard Garfield  Tom
```